# Are The Collector and The Grandmaster related in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, adaptation-comparison

I have heard in the Marvel Comics that The Collector and The Grandmaster are brothers. I have not read these comics so I do not know the exact sources of the information, but I wonder if this relationship (or similar) has been brought into the MCU?

Jeff Goldblum, who plays the The Grandmaster in the MCU, has stated a connection in a podcast interview;

> "I read in my back-story that the Grand Master and his brother, the Collector, played by Bernicio del Toro"
>
> [Begleyesque - Going Green with Jeff Goldblum](https://player.fm/series/begleyesque/going-green-with-jeff-goldblum) (timestamp 47:40)

Where did Mr. Goldblum get this backstory from? Was it from the writers/producers at Marvel Studios or did he read the source comics as part of his own research for the role?

Comment: I wondered about this too. It's certainly stated that they're brothers in the prose novel [The Cosmic Quest: Volume 1](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/The_Cosmic_Quest_Volume_One:_Beginning), but the canonicity of these junior novels is very very low.

Comment: Goldblum said it again at the SDCC when they were announcing the film. He also gave some backstory for the character; https://m.facebook.com/HiddlesPage/videos/thor-ragnarok-comic-con-panel-sdcc-2017/1387572104671494/?locale=en_GB - 14.50 "*Yes, I'm the Collector's brother""*

Comment: I remember seeing a marvael cartoon where two characters who I think were the Collector and the Grandmaster were brothers, I think.  Of course that is a different fictional universe than MCU.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the *[Marvel Studios: Character Encyclopedia](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios:_Character_Encyclopedia)*, the MCU versions of the Grandmaster and the Collector are indeed brothers.

> The Grandmaster rules over the planet Sakaar and is the creator of a deadly gladiator tournament called the Contest of Champions. **He is one of the oldest beings in the universe and the brother of the powerful and mysterious Collector.** He leads a luxurious and indulgent lifestyle from inside his palace tower at the city centre.
>
> [image: Marvel Studios: Character Encyclopedia page 48]

In the comics, the two characters aren't biologically related, however, they're both members of a group of aliens known as the Elders of the Universe, who're said to regard one another as brothers in a figurative sense.

> **The Grandmaster is one of the Elders of the Universe, a handful of ancient and powerful extraterrestrials who have lived longer than almost anyone else in the universe,** their life forces sustained largely by their monomaniacal obsessions with select pursuits.
>
> [...]
>
> Like his fellow Elders, the Grandmaster springs from one of the first sentient races to arise in this universe following the Big Bang, though little is known of his early life or his long-dead native race. **While they come from different planets and species, he and his fellow Elders regard each other figuratively as brothers, given the unique kinship they share as the sole survivors of their universe's earliest civilizations.** The Grandmaster in particular has often taken a keen interest in the activities of his fellow Elders, and tends to assume a leading role on those rare occasions when the Elders act collectively.
>
> [image: Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #4 page 206]
>
> <sub>*[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_4)* (September, 2008)</sub>

While it's possible that Goldblum's belief that the Grandmaster and the Collector are brothers is informed solely (or primarily) by them being stated to regard one another as *figurative* brothers in the comics, it seems more likely to me that someone has informed him that the two characters are meant to be *literal* brothers within the MCU.

They're simply stated to be brothers without the 'figurative' qualification in the official bio for the MCU version of the Grandmaster, and his skin colour was also changed from blue (in the comics) to a brownish orange (in the MCU), which matches the skin colour of the MCU version of the Collector, and implies a conscious decision to make them look like members of the same race.

Comment: Might the comic relation come them being both "Elders of the Universe" which was stated in a now [deleted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/269941/57310)? So not biological brothers, more like "brothers-in-arms"?

Comment: I have wondered if the Grandmaster is so old, how come he didn't know who Thor was in Thor: Ragnarok (2017)? I would think that the Grandmaster would know of Odin and if Odin had sons and daughters.

Comment: @user57467 Time, uh, works differently there. He might think Bor is still fighting the Dark Elves!